# How can I consume wcf when only parameter and url are known

Tags: wcf, httprequest

I have given an web service URL and have known parameter of the method. I want to know how I could access this service with my newly created application. I have to pick only URL and access the service and utilize the given method.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I guess you will need to know what sort of service it is, what's the binding configuration, whether it is SOAP-based service or not. I guess the best way to find out...considering you only know the URL and parameters is to open your browser, make a request and check the response. If you get errors, check the error...it could be a security issue (transport security), an invalid message format which is good indicator of a possible SOAP service, wrong http method (POST, GET, etc.)...the list goes on

If you get a 200 status on the response with some response content, then you know how to consume the service otherwise, ask for more details to whoever gave you this information.

#### Edit

You need to use a tool to generate the client proxy class(es). If using VS you can use the "Add Service Reference..." dialog. You can also use the svcutil command tool. The articles below describe both procedures

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb628652(v=vs.100).aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms733133(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Thnx Leo but it is SOAP based service..!

Comment: Well, check where it is discoverable or not? If not, ask for more details

Comment: It is discover able.....!i exactly want how to communicate with service method of the object of that particular class ....!it is SOAP based service.....thanks in advance

Comment: Thanks Leo itz really helpful but i have not tested i vil test thn further ask my doubts...!

Comment: i have added web reference generated proxy and now want elaborated description how yo access method in this WCF and check the given parameter in new application made to test this service..?

Comment: mate read a tutorial...I have already answered your question...so, please accept the answer and then post another question